# Can I join three factions in fallout 4

Tags: fallout-4

Can I join the railroad, brotherhood and minutemen and still have good relations with each one? If not what should I choose (bear in mind I am already a good bit into minutemen quests) ?

Comment: @DCShannon Not really a duplicate, this question asks if it is possible to join three factions (which it is), while the 'dupe' asks about the limitations of joining. Moreover the accepted answer from the link in the 'dupe' answer is wrong, as it is possible to end the game while having all three above-ground factions alive.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault I don't see how a good answer to "If I join the Brotherhood, will there be other factions that I can't join? Are there any other factions that have such limitations?" could possibly fail to answer this question as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

At some point in the game you are forced to side with one, and that has some effects that are 'game changing' but until this point you can continue to do quests with all of them

Interestingly, depending who you take with you on their quests (so take someone from the railroad on BoS quests) can give you unique dialog and have them making sometimes amusing quips!

Answer (score 1):

*Spoilers ahead*

Yes, it is possible to finish the game while having the Brotherhood, the Railroad and the Minutemen alive. You are not forced to side with one and destroy the others.

However, the quests you have to do are very specific and you have to refrain from talking to a NPC after the game. But you can still do the radiant quests for all three factions.

Here's the relevant part of the [guide](http://steamcommunity.com/app/377160/discussions/0/492379159714925974/) from the Steam Community user Obsidian:

> The process:
>
> Step 1: Before completing "Reunions," complete all main and both side
>   quests (once each) for the Brotherhood of Steel recon team. Talk
>   Brandis down from being crazy.
>
> Step 2: Complete "Reunions" and "Dangerous Minds." (For proper
>   completion, keep Preston at the Castle.)
>
> Step 3: (a) You will have received "Tradecraft" and "Shadow of Steel."
>   DO NOT advance in either of these quests. (b) Focus on the Minutemen
>   as you continue down the main quest line. Use the Minutemen to gain
>   access to the Institute. © Get yourself banished from the Institute.
>   You can play along and poke around for a bit first if you like, but if
>   you do, you'll have to murder someone to get banished (might we
>   suggest those ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥s down in synth retention?). You may safely
>   complete "Institutionalized," but do not progress any farther before
>   getting yourself kicked out. Don't even speak to Father again after
>   completing "Institutionalized." DO NOT complete "Synth Retention."
>   (Give holotape to Sturges.)
>
> Step 4: (a) You will have received "Form Ranks" for the Minutemen. DO
>   NOT advance this quest. (b) DO NOT start "Defend the Castle." Don't
>   even go to the Castle. © Complete all quests for the Brotherhood from
>   "Shadow of Steel" to "Show No Mercy." DO NOT complete "Show No Mercy."
>   Don't even get on the Vertibird. Grab ALL side quests from the
>   Brotherhood and keep them open.
>
> Step 5: Complete "Form Ranks" and "Defend the Castle." Start "The
>   Nuclear Option" for the Minutemen but DO NOT complete it.
>
> Step 6: Complete all Railroad quests from "Tradecraft" to "Randolph
>   Safehouse 6."
>
> Step 7: Complete "The Nuclear Option.
>
> However, don't talk to P.A.M. after this

You will end up with the Institute destroyed but all 3 other factions alive, living peacefully above ground.